# Python equivalent to IDL median() and rot()

Tags: python, rotation, median, idl-programming-language

I'm working with fits images and trying to translate IDL code to python but I'm having trouble understanding how to translate the IDL `median()` and `rot()` functions. I have an array `im_darksub` that is `(ny, nx, n_im)` where `nx,ny` is the shape of each image and `n_im` is the number of images (working with 12 images total). I trying to translate the IDL code `im_median = median(im_darksub,dimension=1)` and `im_medrot = rot(im_median,85,cubic=-0.5)`. I thought that I could just translate this to `np.median()` and `spicy.misc.imrotate`, but I keep getting an error when I use `imrotate`:

```
    Traceback (innermost last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/courtneywatson1/Ureka/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 345, in imrotate
        im = toimage(arr)
      File "/Users/courtneywatson1/Ureka/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 234, in toimage
        raise ValueError("'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for "
    ValueError: 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.
```

Which I'm guessing is because my image array is more than 2 or 3D? Is there a python equivalent for the IDL `median()` and `rot()` functions the way I am using them?

Comment: Check the shape of `im_median` after the `median` call, i.e., `print(im_median.shape)`. Is there a dimension of size 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
x = np.reshape(x, (5, 5, 4))
im_median = np.median(x, axis=2)

import scipy.misc
im_rotate = scipy.misc.imrotate(y, 85, 'cubic')
```

And I assume you saw that `imrotate` is deprecated:

```
/Users/mgalloy/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: `imrotate` is deprecated!
`imrotate` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use ``skimage.transform.rotate`` instead.
```

This seemed to work just fine:

```
import skimage.transform
im_rotate = skimage.transform.rotate(im_median, 85, order=3, preserve_range=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I guess I got confused about translating idl `dimension` to numpy `axis`.